# Can you use xfreerdp to get a console (cmd.exe, command line) session with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, remote-desktop

I am using a Windows 10 computer remotely, over Remote Desktop / RDP, on a Linux host typically running `remmina`.

Unfortunately, the Windows 10 got completely locked for some reason, it would not start any windows, so I tried `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer` - and now I have no icons on the desktop, no taskbar, Ctrl+Shift+Esc does not start Task Manager, Windows + R does not start Run command - I can do pretty much nothing.

I can still connect via RDP to this computer, except as noted, I cannot do anything on that desktop.

Since I have the administrative account on this computer, I though: would it be possible to get a command line `cmd.exe` session over RDP, so I can issue `shutdown /r`?

If so - how? I tried `xfreerdp +fast-path /admin /v:ip.addr:3389`, which according to https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/CommandLineInterface should do:

> /admin Admin (or console) session

... but I still get a GUI log-in, and the borked desktop once I log in?

If not `xfreerdp` - is there another Linux program that would allow me to get a command line session with a remote Windows 10 computer over RDP, so I can issue `shutdown /r`?

Comment: @sdbbs - You should submit a detailed and comprehensive answer instead of submitting a temporary comment that will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - I put it as a comment, because it is not an answer to the question as posed (it is possible to use an RDP connection to issue a command-line shutdown, if desktop is otherwise stuck)

Comment: @sdbbs - Answers don’t always exist given the restraints of a question, if you have solved your question with your solution, that is indeed an answer. Having it as a comment does not serve the community as submitted commentary is temporary. Can’t force you to submit an answer also suggest your comment isn’t permanent